# Rails: How to determine where a helper methods 'points'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, helpermethods

Near the start of this page...

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

... there's an example involving @patient (section 1.2).

I'd like to know how to determine where the following line points:

```
<%= link_to 'Patient Record', patient_path(@patient) %>
```

What about the list generated by rake routes correlates to this?
How do I know which http verb is used?

**EDIT**

I'd like to add that pointing me to 'rake routes' will not explain it for me. I have checked my list of routes many times.

I'd like to know how, in the example on the URL above, I would know where the link_to line points. It seems like the list of routes is significant, but HOW does it correlate with the patient_path line? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

This should give you the answer:

```
bundle exec rake routes | grep patient
```

About HTTP verb, url helpers only determine path/url, they don't determine HTTP method.

Comment: Well, before I type 'bundle exec' into my command prompt would you mind telling me what that does? Thanks.

Comment: I've read the page and I still don't know what it will do. Any advice at all?

Comment: It will 'Execute a command in the context of the bundle', with all gems in appropriate versions required.

Comment: Error: 'grep is not recognized as an internal or external command...'. What am I trying to find out here? Will it let me know how the example on that page works?

Comment: I thought you're running on linux. So run `bundle exec rake routes` and seach for `patient` route manually.